# Construct a matrix according to an arrangement in R

Tags: r

For a given input matrix having 3 rows and 3 columns,

```
1 2 3
5 6 7
7 8 9
```

formulate a matrix where the matrix contains & between any two elements, that is a matrix having 5 rows and 3 columns

```
1 & 2 & 3
5 & 6 & 7
7 & 8 & 9
```

Is there any such command for formulating the latter matrix directly?

Comment: maybe?  But it's really not clear what you're asking.

Comment: More importantly, it's not clear why you would want to create such a matrix. Note that all values will be stored as characters so you cannot even use it for further calculations easily.

Comment: You can try `paste` in combination with `apply` (which will apply `paste` on every row).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your matrix is called `mat`:

```
t(apply(mat, 2, rbind, "&")[-ncol(mat) * 2, ])
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,] "1"  "&"  "2"  "&"  "3" 
# [2,] "4"  "&"  "5"  "&"  "6" 
# [3,] "7"  "&"  "8"  "&"  "9"
```